# GM seeking good reference material on magical fungi, spells that cause plants to grow explosively

Tags: pathfinder-1e, world-building

I'm crafting an eco-terrorist cult. This cult has recently swelled in followers due to the senseless destruction of the forest and disruption of the natural order by an upstart kingdom. Their goal is essentially to 'turn the forest on humanity' by releasing an ultra-fast growing fungus all over the farmlands/heartland of this kingdom. This fungus ordinarily grows fast enough to cause a nasty infestation, but the cultists' leader can use [magic spell] on it, which causes it to mature to a grossly abnormal size and releases poisonous spores. Think like what Poison Ivy does. I want this spell to *permanently alter* the affected fungi, so that they become monstrosities that spawn monstrous children. To that end I imagine she's best suited to be a [blight druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/blight-druid/)... but I cannot find any good analogues for that pesky, all-important [magic spell] she wields. Is it alright if I just make one up?

Also, is there anything out there I could base this fungus off of? If you need a better picture of what I'm talking about, I'm thinking the stuff that grows on the top layers of the [Sea of Corruption](http://nausicaa.wikia.com/wiki/Sea_of_Corruption) in Nausicaa.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I know it seems obvious, but I must ask: are you the GM or is your PC attempting to create this cult in another GM's campaign? Further, I think the title may misrepresent the question. Perhaps a change to something like *Does any effect create monsters from fungus?* is in order? Anyway, thank you for participating and good luck!

Comment: I am the GM. Edited the title to reflect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not completely help you, but check out the [Rise of the Drow](http://paizo.com/products/btpy95ei?Rise-of-the-Drow) book. It is a standalone setting and campaign book (with around 500 pages). It has a lot of detail on fungi in all forms, from food to poisons to weapons. I heard it has a place full of fungi (**Fungi Forest**) that is described on over 50 pages.

Comment: Thank you! There's some great descriptions of fungi to work with, and 'mushroom domain' is what I was looking for.  To anyone else looking for fungi fun I recommend the spells from that list, especially 'fungaltricide'.